How to set the height of an html table element using percentage
I want to make the height of <thead> 10% of parent container, <hbody> 90% of the parent container, and set each <tr> within the <hbody> to 10% of the parent container <hbody> in this case. This way the last row fits perfectly and it wont get cut off.
Here is what I have so far


<div class=" table-container text-sm w-full h-full overflow-y-auto rounded-lg bg-gray-700 select-none text-white ">
  <table class="w-full text-left">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="px-6 py-2">Subreddit</th>
        <th class="px-6 py-2">New Posts</th>
        <th class="px-6 py-2">New Comments</th>
        <th class="px-6 py-2">New Upvotes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="bg-gray-800">
      <tr class="border-b  border-gray-700">
        <td class="px-6 py-2">funny</td>
        <td class="px-6 py-2">12312</td>
        <td class="px-6 py-2">423432</td>
        <td class="px-6 py-2">23432</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>



I tried settings it using tailwind with h-[10%] within <thead> and it has no effect.

Start by making it work in plain HTML. Turning that into React once you have that working is then a trivial step up. But also, what's the point of fixing the ratio of thead vs. tbody when the content isn't fixed? a body that's 9x the length of the header when there's not enough content to fill it is objectively a bad table. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know if I would go so far as to say that having a fixed height for a table body is objectively bad. There are a few examples that come to mind: If you wanted many similar tables to all have the same height, or be able to fit in the same space (for example with the internal content scrolled), or if you wanted a table to fill the entire available space of a modal. I would agree with you that restricting the height of a table may be a bad idea if the internal content will change, and there is plenty of space to expand the height of the table.

table needs to have some fixed height like height: 500px or something else then only its children will use height in percentage in your case 10% & 90% to thead & tbody.
